# create new grayscale mask image by merging two other masks in python

Tags: python, numpy, mask, opencv

I have two masks and the desired mask result as shown below:

[2 original masks and the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weDGJ.png)

I want to create a desired mask result by combining the first 2 masks. Howvever, I only want to produce the white regions if they overlap. IF they don't overlap, then the area should remain black. I'm unsure of how to proceed.

At the moment I have imported the image via cv2 and created a third numpy array based on the dimensions of the original image. I then loop through the two masks and have set a condition based on whether the two values (255 or 0) are the same. If they are then I want to store them or set them in the new mask...:

```
necrosis_mask_observer_1 = cv2.imread(mask1, 0)
necrosis_mask_observer_2 = cv2.imread(mask2, 0)

map = np.empty(necrosis_mask_observer_1.shape)

height, width = map.shape

# do something here?

for i in range(width):
     for j in range(height):

         necrosis_mask_observer_1_sum = necrosis_mask_observer_1[j : (j+1), i : (i+1)].sum()
         necrosis_mask_observer_2_sum = necrosis_mask_observer_2[j : (j+1), i : (i+1)].sum()

         if necrosis_mask_observer_1_sum == necrosis_mask_observer_2_sum:

         #do something here?
         else:
              continue
```

Comment: Are these actually grayscale, or B&W?

Comment: Can you reduce the images to something smaller for a toy example, and construct a sample output by hand to show what result you expect?

Comment: It sounds like you want an "and" operation with floodfill or so

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: At the moment, there is not enough to really go on here. I don't understand what you want well enough to be able to answer. I will have to submit my close vote until you edit your question.

Comment: If they overlap, what will determine the colour of the pixel in the third image? Will it be white if it is white in both of them or in any of them?

Comment: Hi Apologies for the unclear post. I have edited the question with a better example (I think). According to my macbook, they are in the gray colour space, however, I do believe they are binary images- black and white. If the white pixels overlap, then it should be shown in the third mask as white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a bitwise and operation in Python/OpenCV.

Mask1:

[image]

Mask2:

[image]

```
import cv2

# read mask 1
mask1 = cv2.imread('mask1.png')

# read mask 2
mask2 = cv2.imread('mask2.png')

# combine mask
mask3 = cv2.bitwise_and(mask1,mask2)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("mask3.png",mask3)

# show result
cv2.imshow('mask3', mask3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Combined mask:

[image]